# EXCEL VBA- Average all rows containing numerical values for each column in a Merged Area

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple spreadsheets that each roughly look like this:

[image]

I'm trying to find a way to go through each of the SPEAKER HEADERS in Row 1, and summarize the scores that are associated with the corresponding survey question ("Was the CONTENT good?  Was the SPEAKER relevant?  What the DELIVERY good?) grouped by color.

I can't think of a clever way of doing this automatically.

I can get the RANGE SPANS of the Merged Cells like this:

```
  For Each Cell In src_sheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If Cell.Row = 1 And IsEmpty(Cell) = False Then
            MsgBox Cell.MergeArea.Address
        End If
    Next
```

**I then need to iterate over the range provided by the address, getting the numerical values in all the rows BELOW that range.**

For example, running the current macro produces this:

[image]

**I need to take `$C$1:$E$1` and run a for loop that say FROM C1 to E1 average all the numbers in the rows below it.**  I have no idea how to do this.

I was thinking about augmenting the selection in include everything used

Is there a better way to do this?

This is the tragically bad way I'm doing it now (which I'm quite proud of on account of being new to excel):

```
    For Each Cell In src_sheet.UsedRange.Cells
        If Cell.Row = 1 And IsEmpty(Cell) = False Then
            Set rng = Range(Cell.MergeArea.Address) 'Equal to the Address of the Merged Area
            startLetter = Mid(rng.Address, 2, 1)  'Gets letter from MergeArea Address
            endLetter = Mid(rng.Address, 7, 1) 'Gets letter from MergeArea Address

            On Error GoTo ErrHandler:
                Set superRange = Range(startLetter & ":" & endLetter)

ErrHandler:
    endLetter = startLetter
    Set superRange = Range(startLetter & ":" & endLetter)
Resume Next

            superRange.Select
            MsgBox Application.Average(Selection)
```

Comment: I would go about this differently. Create a PERSON class, then for each PERSON and types for each category as persons properties. It would be nice to refer to it as `person_instance.morning_session.content` wouldnt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get rid of the error you are having, you need to change:

```
Set rng = Cell.MergeArea.Address
```

to

```
Set rng = Range(Cell.MergeArea.Address)
```

Ideally, this data would be better stored in a database so that it could be queried easily.  If that's not an option, then the way you are going at it in Excel is as valid as most any other approach.

**EDIT**

Once you obtain the address of the left-most column for each of your speakers, you can loop through each column to obtain averages.

```
'Number of columns in the current speaker's range.
numColumns = rng.Columns.Count
'First row containing data.
currentRow = 4
'First column containing data.
firstColumn = rng.Column
'Loop through each column.
For col = firstColumn to firstColumn + (numColumns -1)
  totalValue = 0
  'Loop through each row.
  Do While Cells(currentRow,col).value <> ""
    totalValue = totalValue + Cells(currentRow,col).Value
    currentRow = currentRow + 1
  Loop
  averageValue = totalValue / (currentRow - 3)
  'Reset the currentRow value to the top of the data area.
  currentRow = 4
  'Do something with this average value before moving on to the next column.
Next
```

If you don't know what row is the start of your data, you can keep checking every row below `rng.Row` until you hit a numeric value.

The method above assumes that you have no blank entries in your data area.  If you have blank entries, then you should either sort the data prior to running this code, or you would need to know how many rows you must check for data values.

Comment: I get this, I was trying to ask another question.  Let's say I do: 

   Set rng = Range(Cell.MergeArea.Address)
            For Each rRow In rng.Rows
                MsgBox rRow.Column

and that yields 3, 6, 9.  What's the best way to do a for loop that says from 3-5, 6-8, and 9 average all the numerical values in the lower rows.

Comment: You dirty dog.  This probably works.  I'll check it out, and let you know.  Take a look at my solution for humor